# Zeppelin Notebook storage in multiple system not working

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am trying to configure Zeppelin to store my repository in multiple system i.e. Git and S3, but it is not working.

It is storing the notes only in S3. My zeppelin-env.sh is pasted below:

```
 export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_S3_BUCKET=xxxx
 export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_S3_USER=yyy
 export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBBOK_STORAGE=org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GitNotebookRepo,org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GitNotebookRepo
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked, when I provided the same information in the zeppelin-site.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're missing quotes in the last statement, the following might work

`export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBBOK_STORAGE="org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GitNotebookRepo,org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GitNotebookRepo"`

and second class can be changed to `S3NotebookRepo` for example